# VSIX - Microsoft.VisualStudio.XmlEditor get SnapshotSpan of node

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio, visual-studio-extensions, vsix

We are using the classes in the Microsoft.VisualStudio.XmlEditor namespace (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.xmleditor.aspx) to parse an xml document in an Visual Studio Extension. Documents are parsed to an object structure, and only changes are parsed. This part is working perfectly.

Now we want to use the parsed data objects to show adornments (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.text.editor.intratextadornmenttag.aspx) on specific locations within the XML file, based on some conditions. The tagging system expects that the extension gives a list of snapshotspans, where the tags should be rendered.

The problem is that we cannot find a way to know the correct positions of the XML tags. The XmlModel class, provides a `GetTextSpan()` method (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.xmleditor.xmlmodel.gettextspan.aspx), but the result of that method call doesn't contain the ITextSnapshot to which the coordinates belong. Since the XML parser is running on a separate thread, there is no way to guarantee that these coordinates are still valid for the most recent snapshot of the text buffer when doing changes quickly after each other. If the result would have been a SnapshotSpan struct (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.text.snapshotspan.aspx), we would be able to translate that span to the current snapshot.

Does anybody know a proper way to resolve this issue?

Comment: Could you please share some code snippet to help us reproduce your problem? Does the XML parser running on a separate thread is default action or designed by your extension? We need more information to understanding your problem.

Comment: It's not so easy to provide code snippets. The XmlEditor service is built-in into Visual Studio.

Comment: Could you explain what's the mean of "the correct positions of the XML tags"? What's the "correct positions" do you mean?

Comment: We would like to add a button in front of some specific XML tags. To be able to do that we need to know the starting position of the xml node in the current textbuffer snapshot.

Comment: The short question is in fact, how can we create a SnapshotSpan object from the Span returned by GetTextSpan() on the XmlModel.

Comment: I am trying to involve someone familiar with this topic to further look at this issue. There might be some time delay. Appreciate your patience.